# sed insert a string into a matched line inside quoutes

Tags: shell, sed

I'm writing a shell script that modifies GRUB options:

```
sed "/^GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=/ s/$/ mem_sleep_default=deep /" /etc/default/grub
```

This sed command matches the line
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quietipv6.disable=1"` but adds `mem_sleep_default` after the quoutes like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quietipv6.disable=1" mem_sleep_default=deep
```

How can I modify this sed to insert `mem_sleep_default inside the qoutes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently matching on the end-of-line  with the search pattern `s/$/`.

Instead you might want to match on the trailing double quote followed by the EOL with `s/\"$/` (Note that you need to escape the double quote with a backslash `\"`)

In the substitution pattern you will need to return that trailing double quote to the end of the line:

```
sed "/^GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=/ s/\"$/ mem_sleep_default=deep\"/" /etc/default/grub
```

Answer (score 3):

try

```
sed "/^GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=/ s/\(\"[^\"]*\)$/ mem_sleep_default=deep &/"
```

where

- `\(\"[^\"]*\)$/` tell sed to remember `\(` ... `\)` a quoted quote \" followed by any other char `[^\"]*` followed by end of line `$`
- `&` will insert remembered pattern